# How do I Connect to remote service from a different .apk

Tags: android, service, apk, aidl

First off I have seen this:

[Remote Service as apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899231/remote-service-as-apk)

And it does not help me at all.  Here is the deal.  I have one apk that creates a remote service (call it A).  I then have another apk (call it B).  How can I connect B to A without include the AIDL file or a jar file.  I would think that this would be possible.

** UPDATE **

So I have copied the AIDL file into B and created an  to the service in A for the AIDL file.  I can conntect to the remote service, and bind to the service now.  However when I try to call a method that exists in the service I get:

java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface

Having trouble finding any help on this.  Any ideas?

** PROBLEM SOLVED **
The AIDL file had to be in a package with the same name in the project B.  Thanks for your help Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know the format of the data that is sent between two separate processes. This is needed for serialization/deserialization of the data to Java objects.

AIDL is a description language to describe the structure of objects.

So, you have two options:

1. Either you have an AIDL, or
2. your code explicitly know the format to do the de-/serialization. This is the implementation of `Parcelable`. This implementation could be inside a jar that you include in your app.

Comment: After thinking more about the situation I'm not opposed to using a jar file.  I think it is actually better that way as I can't see any other way around this problem because I need an object description.  So can I include the AIDL in a jar file?  If I user the AIDL in the project wouldn't I have to implement the interface in the jar file?  What would be the advantage of using a Parcelable over the AIDL?  Thanks for your help.  Your answer to these questions will help me a ton!

Comment: With Parcelable you have to de-/serialize by hand and is only usable if you send Intents, which is kind of limiting. For true IPC you want AIDL.

Comment: Also if your IPC calls are not concurrent, then you can use `Messenger` which queues calls, but does not need AIDL. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Messenger

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I think AIDL will be the way to go.  I'm going to play with it right now and see what I can get working.